# Using a wildcard with "killall" doesn't work other than from /tmp

Tags: bash, process, wildcards, kill

I have `/tmp/bash.sh` that contains a script like this:

```
killall name*
```

It works fine if I go to `/tmp` folder and then run `./bash.sh`, but if I go to `/` then run `/tmp/bash.sh` or `./tmp/bash.sh` it doesn't work.
Instead it complains with

```
name*: no process found
```

Why? How to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `killall` utility does not take a pattern; it takes a list of one or several process names to send a signal to.

What's happening when you say `killall name*` is that the shell will expand the unquoted filename globbing pattern `name*` to all filenames in the current directory that matches that pattern.

You obviously have some filenames in `/tmp` that match this pattern and correspond to the processes you'd like to kill.

When there are no matching filenames, like there doesn't seem to be in the `/` directory on your system, your shell leaves the pattern unexpanded.  The `killall` utility can't find any processes called `name*` and complains about that in the way you report in the question.

---

For a utility that works more like what you expected, consider the `pkill` utility.  With it, you may signal processes based on an *extended regular expression* matching their names.

The following would send the `TERM` signal to all processes whose names start with `name` (note that the pattern should generally be quoted):

```bash
pkill '^name'
```

To signal processes whose name matches `name` exactly:

```bash
pkill '^name$'
```

or, better,

```bash
pkill -x name
```

To also consider the arguments given to the process, use the `-f` option with `pkill`, e.g. to kill the `cat` command that you started by typing `cat myfile`:

```bash
pkill -f -x 'cat myfile'
```

See also the `pkill` manual (`man pkill`).